# Entity Framework add object to new many to many Table Relation Error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, blazor

I have created a new many to many relation on my database between the tables "Items" and "Itemattributes".

Models:

Item.cs

```
public class Item
{
    [Key]
    public int ItemCode { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ItemAttribute> ItemAttributes { get; set; }
}
```

ItemAttribute.cs

```
public class ItemAttribute
{
    [Key]
    public int ItemAttributeCode { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Data Context

```
public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }
public DbSet<ItemAttribute> ItemAttributes { get; set; }
```

Using Commands in package manager console:

```
Add-Migration FunnyNameForMigration
Update-Database
```

Entity Framework creates a Table to Connect the "Items" with the "ItemAttributes" Table, "ItemsItemAttributes".
When i try to create a new Item with 2 ItemAttributes by using the ItemController:

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([Bind("ItemCode")] Item item)
    {
        _context.Items.Add(item);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Ok(item.ItemCode);
    }
```

I get the Error:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
 ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'ItemAttributes' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
```

I guessed that the Item / Itemattribute relation is only on the new "ItemsItemAttributes" Table, why is Entity Framework is trying to add something on the "Itemattribute" table? And how can i add a new Item with ItemAttributes?

**Update**

When I manually insert new connections between the tables "Item" and "Itemattribute" in table "ItemItemattribute", it works fine. I suspect there is a problem with the automatic insertion of entity framework.

Nugets:
[image: Nugets]

Comment: Please expose all the class for Item and ItemAttribute and what you send to the Post action

Comment: Did you add the many to many relation in the OnModelCreating method of the Db Context? Also, as Nicola said, please show us the entire code for your models and DbContext as well as how you are posting the Item.

Comment: @NicolaBiada i added the missing parts from the classes, i sent just a new item object i created to the controller

Comment: @MajdOdeh i did nothing to the  OnModelCreating method

Answer (score 0):

You have to turn Identity on for your PK fields in Items and ItemAttributes:

```
[DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity]
public int ItemId {get;set;}

[DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity]
public int ItemAttributesId {get;set;}
```

Comment: I have used the [Key] DataAnnotation. Does this interfere with your solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're sending the `ItemCode` or `ItemAttributeCode` field in the body of your POST request.

You cannot do it, because these fields are autoincrement and managed by default.
Try to send the model without them.

Comment: No, i can add new Items to the Table, the Error raised when i try to add ItemAttributes to an Item

Comment: Same concept, check `ItemAttributeCode`

Comment: But i added a new Item not a new Attribute. The new Item has a Collection (ICollection<ItemAttribute> ItemAttributes). But what i´m expected is that the entity framework just added a new entry in the "ItemsItemAttributes" Table wich shows the link between Item and Attribute. What do i missing here? I feel like i don`t understand.

Comment: You say: "When i try to create a new Item with 2 ItemAttributes by using the ItemController", so you add an Item with __two__ ItemAttributes inside. How do you create this model ? Could you share your code?

Comment: The entity framework should automatically detect any number of ItemAttribute objects and add them to the communication table it is supposed to create. The problem is not the model. It is too simple the problem is that the Entity Framework does not automatically write to the communication table "ItemItemAttribute".

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'ItemAttributes' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

The error means do not post `ItemAttributeCode` specific value when you create a new `Item` with `ItemAttributes`.

Just post data like below(use Postman as a example):

[image]

Besides, if you use `[Bind("ItemCode")]`, it will only bind ItemCode property data to `Item` and this attribute binds the data from form.

Result Display:

[image]

Environment:

I use **Ef Core version 5.0.6**.

Comment: That's clear, the ItemAttributeCode is Key and is generated automatically for a good reason.

Comment: That's it. So did you resolve your issue now?

Comment: no, I still have a problem with the automatic Insert into the communication table "ItemItemaAttribute" between "Item" and "ItemaAttribute". The error was just a hint, a symptom.

Comment: What's the problem? I could insert into `Item`,`ItemAttribute` and `ItemItemAttribute` successfully.

Comment: As in my question, when I add a new item with itemattributes, the ItemAttributes should insert into the communication table "ItemsItemAttributes" by entity framework. But instead I get an error in the wrong direction.

Comment: So what's the error? As what i said, it works well on my side. Did you try how I post data in my answer? Do not post data with any of the primary key.

Comment: I tried it without primary key and just nothing happend. You have created two modelclasses "item" and "itemattribute" and the entity framework created automatically the communication table? And then it works?

Comment: Yes. I just create two model classed and when I run `add-migration`,`update-database` command, it will generate communicated table `ItemItemAttribute`. Then I post like what i did in my answer(I update a gif about how to post data). It works well. What is your version of Ef core?

Comment: Ef Core version 5.0.8

Comment: I tried to add a new genrated itemattribute without ItemAttributeCode and nothing happend, i have no clue whats wrong

Comment: Could you please share how do you post the data? What does Nothing happen mean? None of the table inserted to data?

Comment: Also, could you please share your solution file to let me check what nuget packages you have installed and what's the version of them?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236435/discussion-between-t0bi-and-rena).

Answer (score 0):

I have no solution for my problem. Anyway, because the communication table is working, i update the table manually. Bad workaround.

```
[HttpPut]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Put(Item item)
    {
        if (item.ItemAttributes != null)
        {
            string delete_sql = $"DELETE FROM ItemItemAttribute WHERE ItemsItemCode = '{item.ItemCode}'";
            _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(delete_sql);
            
            foreach (ItemAttribute itemAttribute in item.ItemAttributes)
            {
                    string create_sql = $"INSERT INTO ItemItemAttribute (ItemAttributesItemAttributeCode, ItemsItemCode) VALUES ('{itemAttribute.ItemAttributeCode}', '{item.ItemCode}')";
                    _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(create_sql);
            }
            item.ItemAttributes.Clear();
        }
        _context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return NoContent();
    }
```